# Full screen android clock

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, clock

Is it possible to get a full screen clock for an android phone which looks something like the clock on the desktop of the computer in this link?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/david_b/3381120183/in/pool-421216@N24/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Night Clock](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.neddashfox.nightclock&hl=en) works well for me (screenshot below), and there are probably plenty of others in the Market. [A search for "big clock"](https://market.android.com/search?q=big%20clock&c=apps) turns up a fair number of hits that seem relevant.

[image]